# Perl: How to sort out all the data matching condition mentioned

Tags: perl, file, sorting

I wish to sort out some parameters from the data below.

For example, if I want to take column 4 PPST and column 5 VDDIFF only, how can I write the counter to take all the data in the file that have PPST and VDDIFF?

If one file has ten devices, how can I get the data for all ten?

My code is below, but it only takes once.

#### Example of 3 devices data in a single file:

```
Device#: 12
Number     Site  Result   Test Name                 Pin            Channel     Low            Measured       High           Force        Loc
0           1    PASS     PPST                      VDDIFF         5         -500.0000 uA   3.8867 uA      1.0000 mA      300.0000 mV    0         
1           1    PASS     PPST                      VDDSE          6         -500.0000 uA   19.2512 uA     1.0000 mA      300.0000 mV    0         
2           1    PASS     PPST                      VDDPLL         7         -500.0000 uA   15.6106 uA     1.0000 mA      300.0000 mV    0         
3           1    PASS     PPST                      VDDIO          4         -500.0000 uA   19.4656 uA     1.0000 mA      300.0000 mV    0         
4           1    PASS     Cont2gnd                  CPUC0          21        -1.0000 V      -432.2093 mV   -200.0000 mV   -100.0000 uA   0         
5           1    PASS     Cont2gnd                  CPUT0          4         -1.0000 V      -432.2228 mV   -200.0000 mV   -100.0000 uA   0        
Device#: 50
Number     Site  Result   Test Name                 Pin            Channel     Low            Measured       High           Force        Loc
0           1    PASS     PPST                      VDDIFF         5         -500.0000 uA   3.6867 uA      1.0000 mA      300.0000 mV    0         
1           1    PASS     PPST                      VDDSE          6         -500.0000 uA   19.2512 uA     1.0000 mA      300.0000 mV    0         
2           1    PASS     PPST                      VDDPLL         7         -500.0000 uA   15.6106 uA     1.0000 mA      300.0000 mV    0         
3           1    PASS     PPST                      VDDIO          4         -500.0000 uA   19.4656 uA     1.0000 mA      300.0000 mV    0         
4           1    PASS     Cont2gnd                  CPUC0          21        -1.0000 V      -432.2093 mV   -200.0000 mV   -100.0000 uA   0         
5           1    PASS     Cont2gnd                  CPUT0          4         -1.0000 V      -432.2228 mV   -200.0000 mV   -100.0000 uA   0     
Device#: 51
Number     Site  Result   Test Name                 Pin            Channel     Low            Measured       High           Force        Loc
0           1    PASS     PPST                      VDDIFF         5         -500.0000 uA   3.5867 uA      1.0000 mA      300.0000 mV    0         
1           1    PASS     PPST                      VDDSE          6         -500.0000 uA   19.2512 uA     1.0000 mA      300.0000 mV    0         
2           1    PASS     PPST                      VDDPLL         7         -500.0000 uA   15.6106 uA     1.0000 mA      300.0000 mV    0         
3           1    PASS     PPST                      VDDIO          4         -500.0000 uA   19.4656 uA     1.0000 mA      300.0000 mV    0         
4           1    PASS     Cont2gnd                  CPUC0          21        -1.0000 V      -432.2093 mV   -200.0000 mV   -100.0000 uA   0         
5           1    PASS     Cont2gnd                  CPUT0          4         -1.0000 V      -432.2228 mV   -200.0000 mV   -100.0000 uA   0
```

#### Perl source code

```perl
open( OUT, ">$outfile" );
open( INF, "$infile1" ) || die( " cannot open input file  \n" );

$count = 0;
$Anam  = 'VDDIFF';
$Nnam  = 'PPST';

printf OUT ( "Unit#  Test_Name   Pin_Name    Measure_Data; \n" );

#while ($line1 ne "")
while ( <INF> ) {

    @temp1 = split( /\s+/, $_ );    #($checkR1 eq "R1")

    if ( $temp1[2] eq "1" ) {       # site =1  on datalog

        print "1 $Nnam $Anam\n";

        $Tnam = "$temp1[4]";        # test name
        $Pnam = "$temp1[5]";        # Pin name

        print "$Tnam $Pnam \n";
        print "\n";

        if ( ( $Pnam eq $Anam ) & ( $Tnam eq $Nnam ) ) {
            $count = $count + 1;
        }
        else {
            $count = 1;
        }

        $Anam = $Pnam;              # save as previous Pnam
        $Nnam = $Tnam;              # save as previous Tnam
        $Mval = "$temp1[9]";
        $Unum = "$temp1[10]";

        printf OUT ( "$count         $Tnam               $Pnam           $Mval $Unum\n" );
    }
    else {
        printf OUT "$_\n";
    }
}

close( INF ) || die "cannot close file1 !!";
close( OUT );

print "all done\n";
```

#### Output expected will be

```
Unit#      Test_Name       Pin_Name        Measure_Data;
 12        PPST            VDDIFF          3.8867 uA
 50        PPST            VDDIFF          3.6867 uA
 51        PPST            VDDIFF          3.5867 uA
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @serenesat Hi , i have included my output expected . Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just check `$TNam` and `$PNam` and only print if they match?

Comment: @Arc676 But only apply for the 1st row am i right?

Comment: Did you really test your code because `$temp1[2] eq "1"` will never match 1, `$temp1[2]` always have `PASS`.

Comment: Always use `use strict` and `use warnings` in your code.

Comment: @serenesat Nope, $temp1[2] eq "1" is "1" . PASS was at [3] . I try it before. I not really know how to do with the count. It give me all the data without matching the $Pnam eq $Anam)&($Tnam eq $Nnam condition

Comment: Please learn `arrays` in Perl and how to get array elements one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have written a lot of unnecessary code. It's my guess that you have taken someone else's program that processes the same input file and attempted to modify it for your own purposes. You should really make a serious effort to solve your own problems before asking others to do your work for you

This program does what I think you want. It expects the path to the input file as a parameter on the command line, and sends output to `STDOUT`, which can be redirected anywhere using the shell

If you save this source in `ppst_vddiff.pl` then your command line should look like

```
ppst_vddiff.pl infile > outfile
```

#### Perl code

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @header = ( 'Unit#', 'Test_Name', 'Pin_Name', 'Measure_Data;' );
my $format = "%-10s %-15s %-15s %-s\n";

printf $format, @header;

my $unit;

while ( <> ) {

    if ( /^Device#:\s*(\d+)/ ) {
        $unit = $1;
        next;
    }

    chomp;

    my @fields = split /\s{2,}/;

    if ( $fields[3] eq 'PPST' and $fields[4] eq 'VDDIFF' ) {
        printf $format, $unit, $fields[3], $fields[4], $fields[7];
    }
}
```

#### output

```
Unit#      Test_Name       Pin_Name        Measure_Data;
12         PPST            VDDIFF          3.8867 uA
50         PPST            VDDIFF          3.6867 uA
51         PPST            VDDIFF          3.5867 uA
```

Comment: Yup,i took others code and modify to get the script i need in the mean time i am learning from the way of writing perl script. I try on the script you write. It work well. Thanks. Beside , i want to ask is there nessecry to have "else" after if statment?

Answer (score -1):

OK, so first off:

- put `use strict;` and `use warnings 'all';` right at the  top of your code. They prevent many errors that will trip you up later.
- 3 argument open with lexical file handles are good. `open ( my $input, '<', $infile )`
- you should always check the return code of `open`, because you'll save yourself a load of pain later.

From this though, your problem is simpler than you think - you have records denoted by `Device#:` so we can set a record seperator. `$/`.

Then we can break down your chunk of data into rows. I would suggest rather than using array indicies, you're better off using named fields in a `hash`:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open( my $output, '>', $outfile ) or die $!;
open( my $input,  '<', $infile1 ) or die $!;

my $pin_name  = 'VDDIFF';
my $test_name = 'PPST';

local $/ = 'Device#:';

#print header row - tab separated
print {$output} join( "\t", "Unit#", "Test_Name", "Pin_Name", "Measure_Data" ),"\n";


while (<$input>) {
    s/\b \b/_/g;    #turn "Test Name" into "Test_Name"
    #split this current chunk on linefeeds
    my @rows = split(/\n/);          

    #pop the first line, and extract the number from it
    my ($device_id) = shift(@rows) =~ m/(\d+)/;    
    next unless $device_id;
    my @header = split( ' ', shift(@rows) );    #read a header row
    for (@rows) {
        my %this_row;
        @this_row{@header} = split;
        if (    defined $this_row{'Test_Name'}
                    and $this_row{'Test_Name'} eq $test_name
                    and $this_row{'Pin'}       eq $pin_name )
        {
            print {$output} join( "\t",
                $device_id,       
                $this_row{'Test_Name'},
                $this_row{'Pin'}, 
                $this_row{'Measured'} ),
                    "\n";
        }
    }
}

close($input);
close($output);
```

Comment: This is turning into a double act, with you providing a solution based around setting the record separatopr, and me writing a state machine!

Comment: Both valid answers to the problem though :)